# Retrieve Flux of iterable from an object

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Coupon service which gives me the coupon based on id and the return type is Mono. Also I have another service to list down all the employees for an organisation with return type Flux.

I want to create a reactive function to return Flux for a given coupon-id. If the `employeeDestinationType` is `'NONE'` then return empty flux, if it is `'SPECIFIED'` then return the set of employee-ids from Coupon object, else if it is `'ALL'` make a call to the external service and return the 'ids' from the Flux.

Here is a reference object.

```
Coupon {
id,                        //Long
employeeDestinationType,   //NONE, SPECIFIED, ALL
employeeList               //Set<Long>
}
```

Below are the method signatures.

```
public Mono<Coupon> findCouponById(long id) {}

public Flux<Employee> listAllEmployees() {}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I was using flatMapIterable to retrieve the values but was running into class cast excdption. The answer from @lkatiforis works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  simply use a `flatMapMany` to achieve this:

```java
  return findCouponById(id) 
      .flatMapMany(coupon -> {
        if(...) {
          return Flux.empty();
        } else if(...) {
          return Flux.fromIterable(List.of(...));
        } else {
          return externalCall();
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks @Ikatiforis, this works! I was using flatMapIterable and was getting casting issues.